# What if I install a 64bit version of ubuntu/kubuntu with less than 4 GB of ram?

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, kubuntu

I need to install a 64bit version of kubuntu (I'd like this one because I like kde, it should not be a problem as repositories are the same, right?) because I need to work with some x64 libraries.

My processos is an x64, old amd dual core, while my ram is just 2 GB.

Is it a problem to install a 64bit version of kubuntu?

Comment: it will work fine.

Comment: ... as long as you have the minimal RAM to run Ubuntu, 512 mb is minimal, 1 Gb is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum requirements for installing Ubuntu and its derivatives (including Kubuntu) are:

- 700 MHz processor
- 512 MB RAM
- 5GB Hard Drive

You should be able to successfully install and run Kubuntu on your hardware.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements for more details.